# Locating in google-maps in desktop

Tags: google-maps, gps

How does google maps find me(geo-locates) when I use google maps in Desktop?Desktops do not have gps receivers like mobiles,then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HTML5 feature, have a read here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp